# C# WindowsForms Raise, consume Events

Tags: c#, events

I have this code below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyCode
{
public partial class Main_GUI : Form
{

    //Attributes
    private Processes process;        
    //Constructor
    public Main_GUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); //a form with a button named BUTTON_Start, and a label named LABEL_log
        p =  new Processes();            
    }
    //OnClickStart
    private void BUTTON_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LABEL_log.Text = "Started...";
            p.start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        //do something with the exception
        }
    }
}//End of Class

public class Processes 
{   
    //Constructor
    public Processes() { }

    //Methods
    public void start()
    {
        try
        {
            //Do something
            //...
            //when finished send an event the Main_GUI Class (Form) in order to change the LABEL_log.Text value to "finished !"             
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //do something with the exception
        }
    }
}   
}
```

I ve tried a lot to create some events, I even use this example :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

but I cant understant how to create an event with my classes...

I such a fool I know but I really need your help !

Thanks the team !!

Regards.

FB

Comment: Study the article some more: your event has no handler attached.

Comment: Thanks to have read the question Plutonix, the problem is that when I used the article in order to create an event, I need in the start() method, to create an objet from Main_GUI class, why ?, because the Subscribe() method (regarding the article) needs to be in "listener" class... so in my Main_GUI class !! So when my event is raised, another Main_GUI is created, and my actual Main_GUI object never receives the event... ! (I know I m a really beginner ... ^^ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the event in the `Process` class:

```
public event EventHandler Finished;
```

Then in the same class define a method that raises the event "safely":

```
protected void RaiseFinished()
{
    // Make sure the event has at least one subscriber.
    if(Finished != null)
    {
        Finished(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

You call the method where you want your event to be raised, in your case the `start` method:

```
public void Start()
{
    try
    {
        //Do something
        //...

        RaiseFinished();            
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //do something with the exception
    }
}
```

Then in your `Main_GUI` class constructor subscribe to the event defining an handler:

```
//Constructor
public Main_GUI()
{
    InitializeComponent(); //a form with a button named BUTTON_Start, and a label named LABEL_log
    p =  new Processes();

    // Subscribe to the event.
    p.Finished += p_Finished;         
}

// This will get called when the Finished event is raised.
private void p_Finished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LABEL_log.Text = "Finished!";
}
```

Comment: SO, but SO easy to understand like that ! Ok mainvoid, let me try it ;) ! By the way thank you for your help !

Comment: @FrenchyBoss I added the method call that raises the event in the Start method.

Comment: Hey budy :D ! That work so hard that I m so excited to continue all my code with events :D ! Thank you very much mainvoid ;) !!